# Mongoose: sort - display results that have parameter equal to [value] first

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my db, every user either **created a movie** or **contributed to a movie** or **both.**

I want to pull all documents from the DB where a certain user participated (either created, or contributed).

But  I want to sort the results such that:

1. **movies he both create and contributed show up first.**
2. **Movies he created show up second**
3. **Movies he only participated in show up last.**

Here is my movie schema:

```
var movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _creator: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    movieName: String,
    credits: [{
        who: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        what: {String} //writer,director,composer, etc.
    }]
});
```

This is my code that retrieves the list of films, but I have no idea how to sort it based on my criteria.

```
Movie
    //find movies that user with id [id] either created or was credited in(participated)
    .find({$or:[ {'_creator':id}, {'credits.who':id}]})
    .exec(function (err,movies) {

    })
```

Can you help?

Comment: You should be able to do this with `movies.sort(function(movie1, movie2){ m1 = 0 if user created movie1 m1++ if user contrib movie1 m1++ and same for movie2 with m2 then compare m1 and m2 return m1 - m2; });` hope it make sense :)

Comment: It makes sense in principal but I am not sure how to implement it in practice. Could you provide a code snippet in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

To sort movies you can use sort method of Array like this:

```
var movies = [
    { created: 'user1', contrib: 'user2' },
    { created: 'user2', contrib: 'user1' },
    { created: 'user1', contrib: 'user1' }
];

var user = 'user1';

movies.sort(function(movie1, movie2) {

    var m1 = 0;
    if (movie1.created === user) m1 = 2;
    if (movie1.contrib === user) m1++;

    var m2 = 0;
    if (movie2.created === user) m2 = 2;
    if (movie2.contrib === user) m2++;

    return m2 - m1;
});

console.log(movies);

//output> first movies user has created and contributed
//        then movies user created
//        then movies user contributed to
[ { created: 'user1', contrib: 'user1' },
  { created: 'user1', contrib: 'user2' },
  { created: 'user2', contrib: 'user1' } ]
```

I believe above code is self explanatory

Comment: It is self explanatory, with that, it means I have to load all the content from my DB before hand, and only then sort it. This in turn means that if I only want to present the 10 entries with the highest score, I have to pull all (possibly hundreds of entries) and only then run the sort. It feels like it would not be very efficient. Am I misunderstanding something?